# Do I need a visa to work in Romania if I have a Bulgarian residence/work permit?

Tags: visa, working-visas, eu, working, non-citizens

Does a non-EU citizen (Turkish) with a Bulgarian residence-work permit need another visa to work in Romania? I have been working in Bulgaria for a time and I got a better job in Bucharest. So am I able to work in Romania without having any visa issues? And if Bulgaria enters the Schengen Agreement, am I going to be able to work anywhere in Europa holding only a Bulgarian residence-work permit?

Comment: Why do you think that your Bulgarian work permit will have any legal powers in Romania? I have no background info (so no answer) but I would fully expect that you would need to apply for Romanian paperwork.